# sumation question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is $\sum\frac{1}{1+2n+n^2}$ from 1 to infinity?

I did

$\sum\frac{1}{1+2n+n^2}=\sum 1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n^2}=\infty+\infty+\pi^2/6=\infty$

but apparently its wrong. But we saw in class that

$\sum 1=\infty$

$\sum\frac{1}{n}=\infty$

$\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\pi^2/6$

so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{a+b}\neq\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$. Otherwise you could go along and say $1=\frac{1}{1}=\frac{1}{1+0}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{0}$ and you have successfully left the realm of that which makes sense.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{a+b+c} \neq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

Comment: Oh yes... How stupid am I... Thanks guys.

Comment: Is it $\displaystyle\sum_{n=\color{red}1}^\infty$ or $\displaystyle\sum_{n=\color{red}0}^\infty$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{1 + 2n + n^2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^2}=-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }1/n^2=-1+\pi^2/6$$